# Main content of page bleeding onto footer? (only in IE7)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

On my [page](http://www.kranichs.com/index_new_template.php) the main content is overlapping onto the footer. this is only happening in IE7. It works fine in ie8,ff,chrome. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IE9.js` attempts to force IE 7 into respecting the `height: 100%` declarations which are actually wrong.

The height of your content should be set to `auto` instead of `100%` because you don't want it to be 100% of height of the container, you want it to fit all your contents.

Here's the modifications to be made in [`main_red.css`](http://www.kranichs.com/assets/css/main_red.css) (I have only included the modified portions).

At line 26:

```
#content_container
{
  background:url(../assets/images/main-layout/logo_bg_red.gif);
  height:auto;
}
#inner_content_container
{
  background:url(../assets/images/main-layout/content_bg_red.gif) repeat-y center;
  height:auto;
}
```

At line 231:

```
#content
{
  padding-top:2px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Wow, how did you figure that out?

Comment: Haha, I had some suspicions when I saw the `100%` declarations but I didn't know IE9.js would do so much. That made things more interesting. :)